# wordpress page as website

Tags: theme-development

I have a website related to information about local info / businesses in certain city and I would to offer business owners in that city a 'one page website'. Their 1 page website is basically using my wordpress page and the address should look like: mycity.com/website/business-name.

Any advice on how to automate this process i.e form to get business name, address, header pictures and description. I'm thinking of something like creating facebook page. This way i dont have to deal with all of the repetitive task to create a standard looking page.

Let me know also if there's a theme for this kind of function

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful guides that may help with the page development in wordpress...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: thanks for inputs. I'm wondering if its posible to get the data that user enter from the contact form and create a page based on the information given through the form?